# Rounding converting from string to double/float

Tags: c++

I am trying to extract a number from a `string` and convert it into a `double` or `float` so I can do some numerical operations on it. I am able to isolate the variable I need so the `string` consists only of the number, but when I try to convert it to a `float` or `double` it rounds the value, ie from `160430.6` to `160431`.

```
//Helper Function to Extract Value of Interest
//Based on column of final digit of numbers being same across various FLOPS output files
double findValue(string &line, int &refN){
    setprecision(100);
    string output;
    
    //go to end column and work backwards to get value string
    while(line[refN] != ' '){
        output = line[refN] + output;
        refN = refN - 1;    

    }
    
    const char* outputx = output.c_str();
    double out = atof(outputx);
    //removing the const char* line and replacing atof with stod(output) runs into the same issue
    
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    string name;
    cin >> name;
    ifstream file(name);
    //opens file
    if(!file.is_open()){"error while opening the file";
    
    }else{
        //Temporary Reference Definitions
        string ref = "TOGW";
        int refN = 25;
        string line = findLine(file,ref);
        
        double MTOGW = findValue(line, refN);
        cout << MTOGW;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I initially tried using `stof()` to convert, but that rounded. I have also tried using `stod()` and `stold()`, and last tried converting to a `const char*` and using `atof()`. I have messed with the `setprecision()` value, but also have not been able to solve it that way.

**I cannot use Boost**

Comment: A `float` can only hold about 6 significant digits, so you really need to use `double`.  Don't know why `stod` would give you problems.

Comment: C++ does not have a `setprecision()` function. `std::setprecision` is an I/O stream manipulator, but you are not using it with any input stream. Also, `findValue()` can be simplified using `std::string::rfind()` and `std::string::substr()` (or `std::string_view` equivalents), or just a `std::istringstream`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there.  The rounding was occurring on output, so that's where you need to use `setprecision`.  That and always use `double` instead of `float` to ensure you have enough precision in your variables.

```
#include <vector>
#include <ranges>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::string;

double findValue(string &line, int &refN){
    //setprecision(100);
    string output;
    
    //go to end column and work backwards to get value string
    while(line[refN] != ' '){
        output = line[refN] + output;
        refN = refN - 1;    

    }
    
    const char* outputx = output.c_str();
    double out = strtod(outputx, NULL);
    
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    string s = " 160430.6";
    int n = s.size() - 1;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(10) << findValue(s, n) << '\n';
}
```

See it in action on the [Godbolt compiler](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM9KuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjE/lykAA6oCoRODB7evv7SyamOAiFhkSwxcWYJdpgO6UIETMQEmT5%2BAbaY9gUMdQ0ERRHRsfG29Y3N2W0Ko32hA6VDFQCUtqhexMjsHOYAzKHI3lgA1CbbbgBu1UTEJ9gmGgCCO3sHmMenxIbAmAo3d49muwY%2By8RxObicLEMeESvweTyBLze4JSBGImFYsP%2BgOBoNOU2IoWAmL%2BXlSRkOU3QIBA%2BMJJyscIe6FWUXohxoDHQADUxF5MBBaeTzAA2WizUiHUIEY5mYVoqjhRYmADsDPuhw1hwA9FqlAREmjkHhUgIIFwNBolds1ZqKajCYdVvqvAR6X9be7NTrgKhDkRDq5DmgsgxDoZ0IcAO4kADWhyiTGQMcjDXQCj9vq%2B0rOvNegqJD1tkYQdH5YrCJgArBZ5eEqwARQ5gMAnRtgDhNjhK1We20ap2JF1vRvlzBVmuYBUNmUWR0uweu629vu14eHVcAWkOXHpHsZ6s1Kvry%2BXaAYUyDCAaACo586CKo1wOXQA6ZAAfXxECtNs1zK8rKvE6a74kQ6AQM%2BD4SuEchBEEP4noWmpogQayhk6bpwsqx77lKhyQqE35/Cqv4avmFJruYZjbsKGiSNsGgvsKVGYQeGp4aGrYUi%2BqQAF78oshxbjuS5IWRBBUigwFgmCdqSXqBrVMa6RmpaSKyRy3K5gKEoMIJMmnJ2VZuAw7asUe7pdvonCVrwfgcFopCoJwbjWNYFKrOsrw7DwpAEJoXbLDGIDbNsL6hRFkVRcK1kcJIdkBU5nC8AoIAaH5AXLHAsBIGgLCJKWZAUBAeUFfQcTAOa2ykFgZx4BsXJ4JgkYAPKJIwnC%2BTQtAELEqUQFEiVRKEDQAJ6dbweVsIILUMLQ40ObwWCQkY4iLTVeCGo4FypetmCqNULqbI5UodIlYpRB8xCjR4WCJfaLATcsVAGMACiNc1bUddwvD8IIIhiOwUgyIIigqOo626AkBhGCgbmWPoeBRKlkDLKgiRdLtG6Uq2piWNYZiOVUNTOBArjjH4CTBLMJRlHoeRpAIFP0ykjMMP0tNDJUHSXLU0zM9znR870HODHElT854LR6FMIs02LEjLAonkbIrsW2aQ9mOc5HaqAAHMKG7CpIhzAMgyDbox2yHBAuCECQMrbFwiy8P5i2LEFIVhVFPsRTFtCcPFmuJTrKVpRl7ukNliAgJB5CUKVhXhKwmz64bxum%2Bb25mC%2BZi8Jg%2BBXHgVIJH9wiiOIwNl2DaiJVDpCRh8iRPerCXrTrLXzkOqBUIcadGybZsW%2Ba4U2x4%2BWFY7zuu5lnuheFvs%2B7FQda7woe2OHbtaB7sV58H7fJRH2/LBcxAmn4khAA%3D%3D%3D).